# How to make SearchView that covers the entire ActionBar/Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, searchview, android-toolbar

How does one create this?

[image: SearchView taking up full ActionBar width/height?]

If you try using a Toolbar and you have inflated MenuItems you'll quickly find out that your Toolbar layout will shrink in width so it does not overlay the MenuItems.

The only thing that comes to mind is inflating a layout and adding it to the Window as an overlay that sits on top of the ActionBar. Remember, this is not a problem if you do not need to inflate MenuItems in your Toolbar/ActionBar as then you are given the full width to occupy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I went with the route of adding my view as an overlay.

```java
/**
 * A Material themed search view that should be overlayed on the Toolbar.
 */
public class SearchView extends FrameLayout implements View.onClickListener {
    // The search input
    private final EditText mSearchEditText;
    // The X button to clear the search
    private final View mClearSearch;

    // Listeners
    private onSearchListener mOnSearchListener;
    private onSearchCancelListener;

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a search is submitted.
     */
    public interface onSearchListener {
        void onSearch(String query);
    }

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a search is canceled.
     */
    public interface onSearchCancelListener {
        onCancelSearch();
    }

    public SearchView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SearchView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public SearchView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        final LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        factory.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_searchview, this);

        mSearchEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        // Show/Hide the "X" button as text is entered/erased
        mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                toggleClearSearchButton(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
        // Add listeners for "Enter" or "Search" key events
        mSearchEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // Allow "Enter" key on hardware keyboard or "Search" key on soft-input to submit
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ||
                            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)) {
                    final String query = getSearchQuery();
                    // Do nothing if query is empty
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query) && mOnSearchListener != null) {
                        mOnSearchListener.onSearch(query);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.cancel_search).setOnClickListener(this);
        mClearSearch = findViewById(R.id.clear_search);
        mClearSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Hide this view until we're ready to show it
        setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked which a search is submitted.
     *
     * @param l the callback that will run
     */
    public void setOnSearchListener(final onSearchListener l) {
        mOnSearchListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked which a search is canceled.
     *
     * @param l the callback that will run
     */
    public void setOnSearchCancelListener(final onSearchCancelListener l) {
        mOnSearchCancelListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the search query.
     *
     * @param query the query
     */
    public void setSearchQuery(final String query) {
        mSearchEditText.setText(query);
        toggleClearSearchButton(query);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the search query or null if none entered.
     */
    public String getSearchQuery() {
        return mSearchEditText.getText() != null ? mSearchEditText.getText().toString() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the search view is visible, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isSearchViewVisible() {
        return getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    // Show the SearchView
    public void display() {
        if (isSearchViewVisible()) return;

        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setAlpha(0f);
        animate().alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(200);
    }

    // Hide the SearchView
    public void hide() {
        if (!isSearchViewVisible()) return;

        clearSearch();

        animate().alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(200);
        // Delay hiding view until animation is complete
        postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 200);
    }

    // LayoutParams for this overlay
    public static WindowManager.LayoutParams getSearchViewLayoutParams(final Activity activity) {
        final Rect rect = new Rect();
        final Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
        final int statusBarHeight = rect.top;

        final TypedArray actionBarSize = activity.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] {R.attr.actionBarSize});
        final int actionBarHeight = actionBarSize.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
        actionBarSize.recycle();

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            rect.right /* This ensures we don't go under the navigation bar in landscape */,
            actionBarHeight,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
            /* Allow touches to views outside of overlay */
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = statusBarHeight;
        return params;
    }

    private void toggleClearSearchButton(final CharSequence query) {
        mClearSearch.setVisibility(!TextUtils.isEmpty(query) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void clearSearch() {
        mSearchEditText.setText("");
        mClearSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void onCancelSearch() {
        // Default is to hide this view unless an onSearchCancelListener is available
        if (mOnSearchCancelListener != null) {
            mOnSearchCancelListener.onCancelSearch();
        } else {
            hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(@NotNull final KeyEvent event) {
        // Handle "Back" key presses
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP &&
            event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onCancelSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.cancel_search:
                onCancelSearch();
                break;
            case R.id.clear_search:
                clearSearch();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_search"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/search"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_actionbar_query_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/search_text_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/search_hint_text_color"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintImageView
        android:id="@+id/clear_search"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is our implementation in an Activity

```java
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.onSearchListener, View.onClickListener {
    private static final String BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH_SHOWN = "key_search_shown";
    private static final String BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH_QUERY = "key_search_query";

    // Keep track of whether the SearchView has been added to the window
    private boolean mSearchViewAdded = false;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;

    // Bundle passed in to onCreate()
    private Bundle mSavedInstanceState;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        mSavedInstanceState = icicle;

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        // This is just an example so you would need to tie this to your own button. This is here so you can show/hide the SearchView.
        findViewById(R.id.sample_btn).setOnClickListener(this);

        // You should have added a Toolbar View to your layout already so reference it here by your id you assigned it
        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            mSearchView = new SearchView(this);
            mSearchView.setOnSearchListener(this);

            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mToolbar != null) {
            // Delay adding SearchView until Toolbar has finished loading
            mToolbar.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!mSearchViewAdded && mWindowManager != null) {
                        mWindowManager.addView(mSearchView,
           SearchView.getSearchViewLayoutParams(SearchActivity.this));
                        mSearchViewAdded = true;

                        if (mSavedInstanceState != null) {
                            mSearchView.setSearchQuery(
                                mSavedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH_QUERY));

                            if (mSavedInstanceState.getBoolean(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH_SHOWN)) {
                                mSearchView.display();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mSearchViewAdded) {
            try {
                mWindowManager.removeView(mSearchView);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Have seen this happen on occasion during orientation change.
            }
            mSearchViewAdded = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mSearchView != null) {
            outState.putBoolean(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH_SHOWN, mSearchView.isSearchViewVisible());
            outState.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH_QUERY, mSearchView.getSearchQuery());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.sample_btn:
                if (mSearchView.isSearchVisible()) {
                    mSearchView.hide();
                } else {
                    mSearchView.display();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearch(final String query) {
        // Handle search here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't this be achieved without implementing a _custom_ `SearchView`, that is by using the `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` ?

Comment: @Solace It can now. This was written prior to Google updating SearchView to be material designed. This is now a good explanation of how to write a custom view that can transition from the top into view and overlay the window.

Answer (score 2):

Use the latest version of appCompat. What you want happens by default in appCompat-v7:"22.1.1". Use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in your menu layout.

Your menu file should look like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"/>
```

All the other code for SearchView would remain same as before.

Comment: I tried it, and it is not working for me =( [Posted a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994512/how-to-make-the-distance-between-left-edge-of-toolbar-and-search-icon-same-as-th)