# SearchView not Expanding after rotation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-widget, android-search

SearchView is working as expected normally but after rotation searchView is not expanding as shown in the below screenshot.I have used onsaveInstancestate() to reset the searchQuery.. Here searchView is not expanding but its showing the keyboard to give input.I have browsed a lot for this but could not find the solution.Please let me know how to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

[image: showing keyboard without expanding the textview]

Xml code for the SearchView [image]

Comment: post your XML code

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133185/how-to-make-searchview-that-covers-the-entire-actionbar-toolbar

Comment: @rakshit Thanks for the link but its not helpful.I am looking for the way that would save my searchView from rotation